# Writing generic math method for nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm wondering if there is a way to refactor this code

```
bool Foo(byte? value)
{
    return value is null || value > 0;
}

bool Foo(short? value)
{
    return value is null || value > 0;
}
```

into generic method like this

```
bool Foo<TNumber>(TNumber? value)
    where TNumber : INumber<TNumber>
{
    return value is null || TNumber.IsPositive(value);
}
```

Is this currently possible in C#?

I tried using generic math but I was getting compiler error CS0313.

Comment: What C# version are you using? I checked and your generic method is possible with C# 11.

Comment: I'm using C# 11. When you try to call this generic method with e.g. nullable int, you get compiler error.

Comment: Please add the error message. Like most people, I haven't memorized all the error codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error states:

> Nullable types can not satisfy any interface constraints.

That's your hint. You need to tell the compiler that the argument is really a `Nullable<TNumber>`, and for that, you have to constraint your generic type parameter to `struct`:

```
private static bool Foo<TNumber>(TNumber? value) where TNumber : struct, INumber<TNumber>
```

And then, you also need to explicitly pass the nullable's `Value` to `IsPositive`, because that method doesn't take a `TNumber?`, and `TNumber?` isn't implicitly convertible to `TNumber`:

```
return value is null || TNumber.IsPositive(value.Value);
```

And with all that, in C# 11, [it compiles](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rNZTWM).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
bool Foo<TNumber>(TNumber? value)
    where TNumber : struct, INumber<TNumber>
{
    return value is null || TNumber.IsPositive(value.Value);
}
```

if you want to also use it with a non nullable, you would have to specify the type.

```
byte a = 5;
Foo<byte>(a);
```